# i can't run my project in android studio - flutter

Tags: android-studio

when i try to run my project in android stodio by flutter for the first time

there is something wrong

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
> Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.10.
> Required by:
> project :
> > Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.10.
> > Could not parse POM https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin/1.7.10/kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.7.10.pom
> > Resetting to invalid mark

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

changed the path
Re-download the program agin.